# Socket.connect doesn't throw exception in Android

Tags: android, sockets, exception, connect

If I put a nonsense url no exception is thrown and none of the rest of my code is executed not even the rest of the asynctask that called the method that connects.

```
try {
        socketCliente.connect(new InetSocketAddress("f", port), 2000);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        getError("Host doesn't exist");
        return -1;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        getError("Could not connect: The host is down");
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: do you have the internet permission? Does this code run on the UI THread?

Comment: Try catching a general Exception instead of IO and UnknownHost Exception? I foresee you might be getting malform URL instead of the 2 you're catching.

Comment: @ChorWaiChun Despite what the OP says, there is no URL in this code.

Comment: @blackbelt, yes it has permissions, I'm trying to treat when a user sets a url that doesn't exist. The connect code is in an object that is created from an asynctask.

Comment: @EJP isn't "f" in `new InetSocketAddress("f", port)` refers to an malformed URL?

Comment: @ChorWaiChun No it isn't. It is a hostname or IP address. URLs aren't used with sockets or `InetAddress.`

Answer (score 0):

Add another catch Statement.

```
catch ( Exception e ) {
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage(),e);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error:" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This will write to the log and pop up a toast to tell you what's going on.

Comment: No exception is thrown, after the connect line nothing else is executed.

Comment: It's probably trying to connect.  It will time out eventually.

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange, can you add two more lines as follows and see what you get.

Also, in the log, pay attention to the time difference between those two lines.

```
try {
    Log.w("SOCKET", "Trying to connect...");
    socketCliente.connect(new InetSocketAddress("f", port), 2000);
    Log.w("SOCKET", "Connected. No exception");

} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    getError("Host doesn't exist");
    return -1;
} catch (IOException e) {
    getError("Could not connect: The host is down");
    return -1;
}
```